# Custom Neutral Culture does not show in Visual Studio Winform Language combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, cultureinfo, regioninfo

We need to create an OEM version of our WinForms app, which would have some different resource strings (OEM branding) than the base (en-US) version. This app is already localized for the neutral Japanese culture (ja).

I am trying to use custom cultures to accomplish this, modeled on an article I found [here](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Using_Custom_Cultures%E2%80%94Company-Specific_Dialects). I have created two cultures: en-US-Acme and ja-Acme. The idea is that, for the OEM English and Japanese versions, we'd set the CurrentUICulture at startup time as appropriate. .Net would then pull the correct resource automatically: looking first in the OEM's resource file (en-US-Acme or ja-Acme), and if not found, falling back to the default resource file (en-US or ja).

I've written a small proof-of-concept app to try this out, and it works great for the specific culture (en-US-Acme). Once my culture is created, I can set the form's Language property to use it, and Visual Studio creates the appropriate resource file. At runtime, the resources are automatically selected (with fallback) as expected.

[image]

There is a problem for the neutral culture (ja-Acme) however: although the custom culture can be created, it does not show up as a choice in Visual Studio:

[image]

My code for creating the custom cultures, adapted from the article mentioned above, is shown below. I am not entirely sure I am creating custom neutral cultures correctly, although the code works.

So two questions:

- Is this the right way to create a custom neutral culture?
- Why doesn't my custom neutral culture show up in Visual Studio?

I am starting to think that custom neutral cultures are just not supported by Visual Studio, and that I'll have to use a custom specific culture (ja-JP-Acme) instead. I haven't tested this yet, but I think the fallback (to ja) would still work as I need.

```
var customCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures( CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture );

if ( customCultures.Any( c => c.Name == "en-US-Acme" ) ) {
    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister( "en-US-Acme" );
}
var builder = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilderHelper.CreateChildCultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( new CultureInfo( "en-US" ), "Acme", "(Acme)" );
builder.Register();

if ( customCultures.Any( c => c.Name == "ja-Acme" ) ) {
    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister( "ja-Acme" );
}
builder = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilderHelper.CreateChildCultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( new CultureInfo( "ja" ), "Acme", "(Acme)" );
builder.Register();

//...

internal class CultureAndRegionInfoBuilderHelper {

    public static CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder CreateChildCultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( CultureInfo parentCultureInfo, string childNameSuffix, string childDescriptiveSuffix ) {
        var cultureName = parentCultureInfo.Name + "-" + childNameSuffix;
        RegionInfo parentRegionInfo;
        CultureAndRegionModifiers flags;

        // Set region info and flags based on whether the parent culture is neutral or not.
        if ( parentCultureInfo.IsNeutralCulture ) {
            parentRegionInfo = null;
            flags = CultureAndRegionModifiers.Neutral;
        }
        else {
            parentRegionInfo = new RegionInfo( parentCultureInfo.Name );
            flags = CultureAndRegionModifiers.None;
        }

        var builder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( cultureName, flags );

        // load the culture and region data from the parent
        builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( parentCultureInfo );
        if ( parentRegionInfo != null ) {
            builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( parentRegionInfo );
        }

        builder.Parent = parentCultureInfo;
        var descriptiveSuffix = " " + childDescriptiveSuffix;
        builder.CultureEnglishName += descriptiveSuffix;
        builder.CultureNativeName += descriptiveSuffix;
        if ( parentRegionInfo != null ) {
            builder.RegionEnglishName += descriptiveSuffix;
            builder.RegionNativeName += descriptiveSuffix;
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the custom neutral culture is indeed shown in Visual Studio, but it is in Japanese, not English, and so was not where I was looking for it. Instead, it was at the bottom of the list:

[image]

Visual Studio is showing the CultureInfo's DisplayName property, and the DisplayName of my custom neutral culture is in Japanese. Why?

I found my answer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15175/NET-Internationalization-The-Developer-s-Guide-to). This is the key sentence:

> Consequently, the DisplayName of a supplemental custom culture is the
>   same as the native name.

The native name is still missing the "(Acme)" suffix, so I may still not be creating the custom neutral culture quite correctly, but this clears up part of the mystery.